# What does delicate mean in this context?

Tags: vocabulary

> Harry looked over at the Slytherin table and saw a horrible ghost sitting there, with blank 
>   staring eyes, a gaunt face, and robes stained with silver blood. He
>   was right next to Malfoy who, Harry was pleased to see, didn't look
>   too pleased with the seating arrangements.
>
> "How did he get covered in blood?" asked Seamus with great interest.
>
> "I've never asked," said Nearly Headless Nick **delicately**.
>
> -- Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

When I come across this word, ***delicate***, it’s not easy to choose proper meaning from dictionaries. From his ruff, I can imagine his attractive appearance; from the situation, a careful way of speaking. What does the word mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to his manner of speaking: as you say, careful, with a suggestion that “That is a personal matter, not the sort of question a gentleman raises.”